# How do I get a copy of the Mavericks installer? It is no longer on the App Store

Tags: macos, vmware

I have looked at the Q&A regarding downgrading from Yosemite to Mavericks, but the Mavericks installer is no longer available in the App Store. Is there a way to get a hold of the installer? Yosemite broke my VMWare and I can't access any of my PC files.

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: your choices are, from a Friend, or from a real apple store. But did you try the cmd-r to see what os is it offering to install?

Comment: Do you still need Mavericks? I have the installer .app file and I can upload it for you. It's absolutely safe, downloaded straight from AppStore when it was available. Next time download every release that is available.

Comment: @slick if you still have it and can upload it to Mega or similar that would be great